# Is Topological sort different from DFS only in that processing of current element is done after recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

Is Topological sort different from DFS only in that,

- In case of Toplogical sort, the processing (adding to an output
  stack) of current element is done after recursive call, whereas,
- In case of DFS, the current element is processed (that is, printed or
  added to an output queue) before the recursive call?

This is my code for DFS

```
public void depthfirstsearchrecursive()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<vertices.size();i++)
        {
            if(vertices.get(i).isVisited == false)
            {
                vertices.get(i).isVisited = true;
                System.out.println(vertices.get(i).name + " ");
                depthfirstsearchrecursiveUtil(vertices.get(i));
            }
        }
    } 
    public void depthfirstsearchrecursiveUtil(Vertex v)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<v.neighbors.size();i++)
        {
            if(v.neighbors.get(i).isVisited == false)
            {
                v.neighbors.get(i).isVisited = true;
                System.out.println(v.neighbors.get(i).name + " ");
                depthfirstsearchrecursiveUtil(v.neighbors.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I print the element first, then, make the recursive call.

This is my Topological sort implementation

```
/* topological sort recursive */
    public void topologicalsortrecursive()
    {
        Stack<Vertex> output = new Stack<Vertex>();
        for(int i = 0;i<vertices.size();i++)
        {
            if(vertices.get(i).isVisited == false)
            {
                vertices.get(i).isVisited = true;
                topologicalsortrecursiveDriver(vertices.get(i), output);

//              System.out.println(vertices.get(i).name + " ");
                output.push(vertices.get(i));
            }
        }
    } 
    public void topologicalsortrecursiveDriver(Vertex v, Stack<Vertex> output)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<v.neighbors.size();i++)
        {
            if(v.neighbors.get(i).isVisited == false)
            {
                v.neighbors.get(i).isVisited = true;
                topologicalsortrecursiveDriver(v.neighbors.get(i), output);

//              System.out.println(v.neighbors.get(i).name + " ");
                output.push(v.neighbors.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, the processing (pushing into a stack, is done after the recursive call is made)

Is it true to say that,

- DFS is like a PreOrder traversal, where we process the element, then
  go to it's children, whereas,
- Topological sort is like a reverse Post order traversal, where we go
  to children first, and then process the current element, by pushing
  them to a stack, (which is why I said **reverse** Postorder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. DFS is the generic form. You can use it to implement a pre and/or post order evaluation.

Topological sort requires a post evaluation DFS.

Consider the following code:

```
void DFS(Vertex v) {
  if (v.hasVisited)
    return;
  v.hasVisited = true;
  doBeforeDepth(v)
  for (Vertex u : v.neighbours)
    DFS(u);
  doAfterDepth(v);
}

void DFS()
{
    for (Vertex v : vertices)
        DFS(v);
}
```

You can use this DFS code to perform topological sort.